# JQuery change id attribute of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a drag and drop thing which uses clone.  I am having a problem with the date clone though because of datepicker.  Therefore, I need to make sure each cloned datepicker has a unique id.  A cloned element looks like the following

```
<div data-type="date" class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-5" for="dateInput">Date Input:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <input type="text" name="dateInput[]" class="form-control date_picker" id="dateInput">
    </div>
</div>
```

So if I clone two date inputs, I will have two of the above.  Now on submit, I clean all of the cloned html, doing things like removing the data-type.  At this stage, if there is a cloned date input, I need to give it a unique id.  At the moment I am doing this

```
$("#content").find(".form-group").each(function() {
    var html = $(this).attr('class', 'form-group')[0].outerHTML.replace(/ data-(.+)="(.+)"/g, "");
    var input = $(this).find('input');
    var i = 0;
    if(input.attr('id') == 'dateInput') {
        alert("TEST");
        input.attr("id",'dateInput' + i).datepicker();
        i++;
    }
    console.log(html);
    dataArray.push(html);
});
```

The TEST alert fires twice as it should do if I clone 2 date inputs.  However, the id attributes do not seem to change when I output the html to the console.  I have set up the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/) to demonstrate that the id of the element is not changing.

Any advice on getting this to change appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Where is `id` of `input` changed before being displayed ? `.clone()` not appear used at jsfiddle ? Is requirement to change `id` of string displayed at `#output` ?

Comment: This is occuring after the clone, what I have posted above is when I submit the cloned form.  So I essentially need to change it before I add it to an array.

Comment: Is requirement to replace `id` at string representation of `input` element displayed at `#output` ?, or change `input` element `id` within `DOM` ?

Comment: Well really I save the html variable to an array.  The html variable contains all the html code.  The id needs to be unique when saved to this array

Comment: Is `html` variable a string or jQuery object ? Also note, `dataArray` does not appear to be defined at jsfiddle ?

Comment: It should be a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining `dataArray`, `i` outside out `submit` event, `.each()` , using `.map()` , `.get()` , `.attr(function() {index, attr})` , `.outerHTML`

```
$(function() {
    // define `i` , `dataArray`
    var i = 0, dataArray = [];
    $('#content').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#content").find(".form-group").each(function() {
          var html = $(this).attr('class', '.form-group')[0]
                     .outerHTML.replace(/ data-(.+)="(.+)"/g, "");
          dataArray.push($(html).map(function(_, el) {   
            // adjust `input` `id` here , return `input` as string 
            return $(el).find("input").attr("id", function(_, id) {
              return id + (++i)                
            })[0].outerHTML
          }).get()[0])
        });   
        $("#output")[0].textContent = dataArray.join(" ");
        console.log(dataArray)
    });
});
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/2/

Comment: This works great.  Is there any way to keep the label of the input as well?

Comment: @kate_hudson _" Is there any way to keep the label of the input as well?"_  Yes, perform same process on `label` element within `.each()` that is performed for `input` element jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/3/

Comment: Thats perfect :-) One last question - say I had inputs of other types e.g. text inputs or textarea inputs.  Is there a way to capture everything like the above, but only perform te id change on date inputs?

Comment: Sorry, also, is it possible to keep the whole group together?  So instead of just label and input, these should be withing their form-group div just like the original.  Essentially, I am trying to replicate the original blocks, just with different ids

Comment: Yes, select only date inputs within `.each()` .  Yes, use `.html()` to set variable `html` to `input`, `label` variables after `.attr()` calls which adjust their `id`, `for` attributes

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I have updated the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/5/  I have made some progress, but the way I do it the original date is being added when I push the html variable.  So the output has 4 code blocks instead of 3.  How can I amend this?  Thanks

Comment: What is "original date" ?

Comment: So if you see the fiddle I added, it just replicate the original html code, but change any inputs with an id of dateInput to have a unique date.  If you check out the code which is alerted, you can see that it outputs more than the original three blocks

Comment: Try adjusting https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/3/ to change `html` variable `html` to be `label` , `input` variables `.outerHTML`

Comment: Sorry, slightly confused.  How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Probably not the neatest, but think I am geting there https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/6/  Just got to work out how to put te date label and input into a form-group div

Comment: Ok, this now outputs what it should do https://jsfiddle.net/mLgrfzaL/7/  Is it possible to clean it up, not sure I need to add the divs manually, but couldnt find a different way to do tis

Comment: Is it possible to make the name of the date input the same as the id?